# How to check by bash on Linux the full Firefox browser or the FF browser tab has crashed or frozen

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, tabs, crash

I have a FF Browser which open and show a website, p.e [www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com)

How to check by bash the full browser or the tab which show [www.sample.com](http://www.sample.com) has crashed or frozen?

Its already clear for me:

- how to open and close browser by bash

Comment: I do not believe it is possible.

Comment: It can be its possible to check the tab or the browser crashed or frozen a by process manager.

Answer (score 0):

*To open firefox using Bash write in bash prompt* : **firefox**

*To close firefox using Bash write in bash prompt*  : **killall firefox**

Comment: How to open and close the FF are not the question. The question are: 
How to check by bash the full browser or the tab which show www.sample.com has crashed or frozen?

Comment: Thats answer is not releated to the question.